# Network latency, battery and load simulation tools for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

There is some hybrid app I need to test. I need to test it in Android and iOS.

I have device Samsung SII and iPhone 4s.

I tried to test it with different means.

By simulating the network/battery/memory.

I need some tools that would help me in that.

i.e., When the battery is full, I need to reduce it to Low and test it. And when there is lot of memory, I need to reduce it and test the app in Low memory. And when the bandwidth speed of the network is high, I need to reduce it and test the app.

Can any one suggest me tools that simulate these. Never mind it is 3 different tools or a single tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just simulate on a real device.

For simulation use simulators - both Android and iOS simulators have features enabling you to simulate battery/memory/incoming calls and many other events.

If you want to do something on real device, you have to do it the hard way - let the battery drop (e.g. playing 3D games), switch internet connection off, make a call from another device to get an incoming call...

For low memory simulation, try to run a 3D game in the background, play audio/video etc.